# Angular 6 Feature Modules : Interceptor not firing

Tags: angular

I'm using feature modules for the first time and cannot get an interceptor to fire. I'm new to the feature model pattern and am hoping somebody can point out an obvious error in my understanding. The interceptor is called "AuthenticationInterceptor". I have pasted my code below and would greatly appreciate any help.

The structure of my codebase is as follows:

/app

```
app.module.ts
...
/dashboard
    dashboard.module.ts
    dashboard-routing.module.ts
    dashboard.component.ts
    ...
/core
    core.module.ts
    ...
/shared
    shared.module.ts
    ....
```

APP.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module'
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module'
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AuthenticationInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/authentication.interceptor'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    DashboardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
        multi: true
    } 
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

APP-ROUTING.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    },
    { 
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true } )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

SHARED.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { 

  static forRoot() {

    return {
        ngModule: SharedModule,
        providers: []
    }
  }
}
```

CORE.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthenticationInterceptor } from './interceptors/authentication.interceptor'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ]  
})
export class CoreModule {

    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {

        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error('CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {

        return {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [
                AuthenticationInterceptor
            ]  
        }
    }    
}
```

DASHBOARD.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module'
import { AuthenticationInterceptor } from './../core/interceptors/authentication.interceptor'

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module'
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

DASHBOARD-ROUTING.MODULE.TS

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './../core/guards/authentication.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    { 
    path: '', 
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [
            AuthenticationGuard
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: 1) Not use: 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
It is the old deprecated module
2) How you send a request?

Comment: 3) You should provide interceptors only in Core module. Remove other imports;

Comment: 4) Not import core module two times (like in app.module imports)

Comment: 5) Use barrel's index.ts and set up config.ts. Read more about it there: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81

Comment: thanks @DmitriyIvanko! I followed your suggestions and got it working. Changed my code so only the core module is providing the interceptor and swapped out the Http module as suggested. I shall try and put a complete answer together for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, @prime, no problem)

Answer (score 12):

If you import `HttpClientModule` every time for feature module then for every instance of a module there is a new instance of `HttpClientModule`. That's why your interceptor is not working. Import `HttpClientModule` only at `app.module.ts` and it will intercept all HTTP requests.